# Import from parent folder

Tags: python

I have a folder structure as:

```
├── helper_files
│   ├── CONSTANTS.py
│   ├── bps.py
│   ├── bpsRestPy.py
│   └── helper.py
└── script_files
    ├── device_cleanup_script.py
    ├── device_sp_heavy_script.py
    ├── image_upload_script.py
    ├── profile_7_script.py
    ├── profile_9_script.py
    ├── shut_all_interfaces_script.py
    └── test.py
```

From test.py I want to access the helper.py, but the below one fails. Whats the correct way?

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path

path = str(Path(Path(__file__).parent.absolute()).parent.absolute())
sys.path.insert(0, path)

from helper_files import helper

helper.my_logger()
```

Comment: why not packaging?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
from ../helper_files import helper
```

it works for me

Comment: hello, it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this I hope this works.

```py
import sys
sys.path.append(r'../helper_files') # relative path 

import helper
```

#### OR YOU COULD CHANGE THIS TO

```py
import sys
sys.path.append(r'../')

from helper_files import helper
```